# Overloading operator + and doing a + b where a is int and b custom object

Tags: c++, oop, operators

I've overloaded + operator for my custom class when the second argument is int. For example if my object is x, then x + 7 is possible while 7 + x is not. How can I make the latter possible?

I think including my class code is not necessary here.

Comment: Can I make it inside the class?

Comment: @jsk9 No, you can't add `operator+` for `int + custom object` in the class but for `custom object + int` it would work by adding `obj_type operator+(int) const`

Comment: @jsk9 See eerorika's answer. You usually define a free standing overload like that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo and eerorika: is this not an extremely clear duplicate of the thread I linked to above? I'm yet to receive a c++ gold badge so I cannot apply the dupe hammer here.

Comment: @dfrib Though, answering such questions (instead of just flagging them as duplicate) could bring you closer to the C++ gold badge... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff In this particular case I answered the exact same question yesterday (the linked thread is from yesterday and answered by myself), so that would be a tad bit too vampiric :D

Comment: @dfrib This might have been the one where I added a close vote with the same link for duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Overloading operator + and doing a + b where a is int and b custom object

By defining the overload `operator+(int a, custom b)`.

It may however be preferable to make the custom type implicitly constructible from int in which case you would only need one operator overload `operator+(custom a, custom b)` which would work with all combinations of `custom` and `int`.

Comment: How to make the custom type implicitly constructible from int?

Comment: @jsk9 You add a converting constructor. `custom::custom(int x);`

Comment: Oh, ok. Btw seems like there is no way to keep it into the class right? Like I should define it outside. (I mean this operator overloading function).

Comment: @jsk9 If it is a friend function (and it typically has to be), then it can be defined within the class definition. But that's not necessary.

Comment: I've added `operator+(custom a, custom b)` as well as converting constructor and erased the previous function `operator+(int n)`, still it does not work. It says that operator + is ambiguous.

Comment: Can templates be the reason?

Comment: @jsk9 Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/8GMvWo) - If you have code that doesn't work you need to create question and include the code. Make a [mcve].